# Sort list of lists of dictionaries by datetime in python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I would like to sort a list of books that is returned by the Google Books API by the date published of the books. The data looks something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 506,
 "items": [
   {
  ...
     "volumeInfo": {
       "title": "RHYTHM OF WAR PART ONE",
       "authors": [
         "BRANDON SANDERSON"
       ],
       "publishedDate": "2023-03-16",
       "industryIdentifiers": [
         {
           "type": "ISBN_10",
           "identifier": "1473233372"
         },
   ...
   },
```

What I have tried is first first isolating the books in a new list like so:

```
myList = myList["items"]
```

And then sorting the new list by datetime.

```
myListSorted = sorted(myList, key=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
myListSorted = sorted(myList, key=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["publishedDate"]["volumeInfo"], '%Y-%m-%d'))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I have also tried using the itemgetter method, but have not been successful so far.

The results of the API calls can be sorted by date published like so:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:brandon%20sanderson&orderBy=newest

But I am adding the results of several calls together in one list and would like to be able to sort all of the books by release date.

Comment: The error message indicates that you're indexing into something that's a list rather than a dict - that is, `d` or (if the error is actually from the earlier line) `myList` is not what you think it is or is not from data that's exactly as shown. My _guess_ is that there's something off about how you've assigned `myList`, this code snippet isn't exactly wrong but it's suspicious: `myList = myList["items"]`. I would usually give the items-only list a new name for clarity, eg `volumes = myList["items"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be elsewhere in your code, as this does minimally what you said you did, but has no issues:

```
from json import load
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime

with urlopen('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:brandon%20sanderson&orderBy=newest') as r:
    data = load(r)
    items = data['items']
    sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"], '%Y-%m-%d'))

print(sorted_items)
```

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, if you do still have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have been adding the results of the API calls together incorrectly.

Now I am getting 
ValueError: time data '2021' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

so I am going to look into dealing with values that do not have the format I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out your problem!

In your second `myListSorted` statement, you got the dictionary arguments the wrong way around!

Try this:

```py
myListSorted = sorted(myList, key=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to switch around the arguments when it didn't work and accidentally copied the error message for an earlier execution of the code. I have since figured out that things were going wrong at a different point in my code.

Comment: @MD, no problem! Glad you figured it out!